# FluentNHibernate: mapping a nullable int Version property

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, version, nullable, conventions, automapping

How do I map a Version property using conventions (e.g. IClassConvention, AutomapperConfiguration)?

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    ...
    public virtual int? Version { get; protected set; }
    ...
 }

<class ...>
    <version name="Version" column="version" generated="never" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0" />
</class>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Version from an int? to an int.

FluentNHibernate automatically identifies a property called "Version" or "Timestamp" as a versioning field. However it must be one of a few types (int, long, TimeSpan, byte[]). See VersionStep in the FNH source.

You can customize this column with IVersionConvention (just not choose which property is your version). I saw a [post from Fabio Maulo](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/03/conform-mapping-aspnet-membership.html) that hints this feature may be in the trunk already.